# how to assign the values to a contenteditable div in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text editor and I want to pre-populate all the fields if I open the text editor to edit something. The input and textarea have been doing fine but as soon as I wanted to add the div contenteditable, then there is an error saying `newText` is not defined even though I defined it. I did exactly the same as I did with the other fields but somehow it's not recognizing, not sure how do I prepopulate the contenteditable div too.

this is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-hooks-3bvg8?file=/src/Editor.js:3736-4031) where you can see a demo of the problem.

editor.js

```
class Editor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
      enteredText: "",
      newText: ""
    };
    this.commonChange = this.commonChange.bind(this);
  }
commonChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //Load the snippet
    if (this.props.match.params.snippetId) {
      const snippetId = this.props.match.params.snippetId;
      console.log("this.props.match.params.snipped", this.props.match);
      console.log(this.props.snippets);
      if (this.props.snippets && this.props.snippets.length) {
        const data = this.props.snippets.find(
          snippet => snippet.snippetId === snippetId
        );
        console.log("data", data);

        this.setState({
          title: data.snippetTitle,
          enteredText: data.snippetDescription,
          newText: data.snippetDescription
        });
      }
    }
  }
render(){
  return {
   <div
          contentEditable={true}
          name="newText"
          value={newText}
          className="textareaclass"
          placeholder="Enter your text here"
          onChange={this.commonChange}
          id="entered-text-area"
        />
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: <div
          contentEditable={true}
          name="newText"
          className="textareaclass"
          placeholder="Enter your text here"
          onChange={this.commonChange}
          id="entered-text-area"
        >{this.state.newText}</div>

Comment: https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable
This might help you

Comment: it worked with your solution.. thanks. I saw the package but didn't want to install anymore packages. how do I accept your solution as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content editable is accept the text content inside the div so you might need to add the text inside the div

```
<div contentEditable={true} name="newText" className="textareaclass"
    placeholder="Enter your text here"
    onChange={this.commonChange} id="entered-text-area">
    {this.state.newText} <!---- as this -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
render(){
  return {
   <div
          contentEditable={true}
          name="newText"
          value={this.state.newText} // access state newText
          className="textareaclass"
          placeholder="Enter your text here"
          onChange={this.commonChange}
          id="entered-text-area"
        />
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not prepopulated though. i have updated the sandbox, you can see that if you go to homepage and open one of the snippet then the input and textarea is filled with data on mount but no data for the `div`